# Aws ALB Traefik 404 not found with IngressRoute

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, traefik, argocd

I deployed my EKS clusters and configure to use Cilium as CNI and for networking. I have an app project setup with ArgoCD in order to maintain all my workloads in my repo. When I deploy my Traefik on EKS with all the ressources needed like cert manager and so on. But when I try to reach out my Traefik dashboard from m y ELB created on EC2 load balancer I'm getting an 404 and when I look to my pods all are running without issues as you can see in the images below.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/an6tm.png)

Also when I look at the traefik pod log I can see the ping is working but when I access /dashboard I get the 404.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g29MV.png)

My traefik dashboard manifest:

```
---
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: Certificate
metadata:
  name: traefik-dashboard
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  commonName: traefik.baobabservices.net
  secretName: traefik-dashboard
  dnsNames:
    - traefik.example.net
  issuerRef:
    name: acme-prod
    kind: ClusterIssuer
---
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRoute
metadata:
  name: traefik-dashboard-web
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  entryPoints:
    - web
  routes:
    - match: "Host(`traefik.example.net`) && PathPrefix(`/dashboard`)"
      kind: Rule
      services:
        - name: api@internal
          kind: TraefikService
      middlewares:
        - name: http-https-redirectscheme
          namespace: kube-system
    - match: "Host(`traefik.example.net`) && PathPrefix(`/api`)"
      kind: Rule
      services:
        - name: api@internal
          kind: TraefikService
      middlewares:
        - name: http-https-redirectscheme
          namespace: kube-system
---
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRoute
metadata:
  name: traefik-dashboard-websecure
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  entryPoints:
    - websecure
  routes:
    - match: "Host(`traefik.example.net`) && PathPrefix(`/dashboard`)"
      kind: Rule
      services:
        - name: api@internal
          kind: TraefikService
    - match: "Host(`traefik.example.net`) && PathPrefix(`/api`)"
      kind: Rule
      services:
        - name: api@internal
          kind: TraefikService
  tls:
    secretName: traefik-dashboard
```

Comment: Can you show the `api@internal` traefik service? If it's not in the same namespace as traefik, you must also specify the namespace. Is `traefik.example.net` replaced with a functional dns name in your actual setup?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It was related to the chart version that I was using. Thank you @jordanm .